# Creating Survival Trees with MST package: Undefined Columns Error?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to create a survival Tree with the MST package from R. I have been looking into [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiIkYrjpJHjAhXxTxUIHXdpBC0QFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv083i12%2Fv83i12.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1s-K37yGPD6IEf6musqcKT) paper.

I replicated their example with randomly generated Data and it works just fine. I adjusted my data to fit the same model. My data has the same columns and the same datatypes.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf_data[col.split.var], , 3) : undefined columns selected
```

with the following line of code:

```
fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time,status)  ~ x1 + | id), data = data)
```

I have looked through all of the documentation and I didnt find anything and I can't understand why this error appears.
The code form the paper looks like this:

```
set.seed(186117)
data <- rmultime(N = 200, K = 4, beta = c(-1, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0),cutoff = c(0.5, 0.3, 0, 0), model = "marginal.multivariate.exponential", rho = 0.65)$dat
test <- rmultime(N = 100, K = 4, beta = c(-1, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0), cutoff = c(0.5, 0.3, 0, 0), model = "marginal.multivariate.exponential",rho = 0.65)$dat
fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | id,data, test, method = "marginal", minsplit = 100, minevents = 20,selection.method = "test.sample")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and I do get an error although not the one you are getting and I'm fairly sure after looking at it that you need to use the [edit] features of SO to modify your question.

```
> fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time,status)  ~ x1 + | id), data = data)
Error: unexpected '|' in "fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time,status)  ~ x1 + |"
```

The formula give is obviously wrong and there is an unnecesary closing parentheses. I am able to get teh error you report with:

```
> fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time,status)  ~ x1 | id, data = data)
[1] "No test sample supplied, changed selection.method = 'bootstrap'"
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf_data[col.split.var], , 3) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

.... but not with the original code:

> fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | id,data, test, method = "marginal", minsplit = 100, minevents = 20,selection.method = "test.sample")

I also see an erroir with `x1+x2|id` on the RHS of the formula but not with three variables:

```
> fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x1 +x2 | id,data, test, method = "marginal", minsplit = 100, minevents = 20,selection.method = "test.sample")
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf_data[col.split.var], , 3) : 
  undefined columns selected
> fit <- MST(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x1 +x2+x3| id,data, test, method = "marginal", minsplit = 100, minevents = 20,selection.method = "test.sample")
```

So I'm thinking is is a bug that the developers had not anticipated. Here's how to obtain the needed email address to report:

```
> maintainer("MST")
[1] "Peter Calhoun <calhoun.peter@gmail.com>"
```